# Formatted TextField input has problem with cursor

Tags: swift, swiftui, cursor, textfield

Hi I got code below and try do formatting text input dynamically but when everything looks good and I'll try to edit cursor jump to the end which looks strange and my question is can we prevent this behaviour.

The issue is demonstrated below in the gif.

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text = ""
    @State private var error: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            let config = _TextFieldConfig(titleKey: "",
                                          promptText: "Enter text here",
                                          value: $text,
                                          error: $error,
                                          format: ._parseableFormatStyle)
            _TextField(config: config)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct _TextFieldConfig<Format: ParseableFormatStyle> where Format.FormatOutput == String, Format.FormatInput == String, Format.Strategy == _ParseStrategy {
    var titleKey: String
    var promptText: String
    var format: Format
    @Binding var value: String
    @Binding var error: String?
    
    init(titleKey: String = "",
         promptText: String = "",
         value: Binding<String>,
         error: Binding<String?>,
         format: Format) {
        self.titleKey = titleKey
        self.promptText = promptText
        _error = error
        _value = value
        self.format = format
        
    }
}

struct _TextField: View  {
    var config: _TextFieldConfig<_ParseableFormatStyle>
    
    init(config: _TextFieldConfig<_ParseableFormatStyle>) {
        self.config = config
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField(config.titleKey,
                      text: config.$value,
                      prompt: Text(config.promptText))
        }
        .onChange(of: config.value, initial: false) { oldValue, newValue in
            config.value = oldValue.formatted(config.format)
        }
    }
    
    
}

struct _ParseStrategy: ParseStrategy {
    func parse(_ value: String) throws -> String {
        value
    }
}

struct _ParseableFormatStyle: ParseableFormatStyle {
    var parseStrategy: _ParseStrategy { .init() }
    
    func format(_ value: String) -> String {
        value
            .lazy
            .filter { $0 != " " }
            .chunks(ofCount: 2)
            .map { String($0) }
            .joined(separator: " ")
    }
}

extension ParseableFormatStyle where Self == _ParseableFormatStyle {
    static var _parseableFormatStyle: _ParseableFormatStyle { .init() }
}

extension Array {
    func chunks(ofCount chunkCount: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        var result: [[Element]] = []
        for index in stride(from: 0, to: count, by: chunkCount) {
            let lastIdx = Swift.min(count, index + chunkCount)
            result.append(Array(self[index ..< lastIdx]))
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I haven't found anything that could manipulate the cursor in SwiftUI's TextField, but it might not be the source of the problem either.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with pure SwiftUI. IMO this is rather bad UX anyway. I suggest formatting the text after the text field loses focus. You can easily do that using the `format:` parameter.

Comment: There is such a possibility, but I am currently trying to see if it's possible to create a workaround using UIKit e.g.

Comment: You can always use UIKit. Just implement `shouldChangeCharactersIn` of the text field delegate.

Comment: A found a limited number of solutions but in very case there is something wrong with editing. Do you have any tips to implement shouldChangeCharactersIn with limit e.g. 9 letters without whitespace?